# What are the gauntlets joined by a cable used in Ushaan called?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-enterprise, andorian

In the Star Trek Enterprise season four episode [United](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/United_%28episode%29), the Andorian ritual [Ushaan](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Ushaan) is depicted. It is a duel to the death with the Andorian ice miners tool [Ushaan-tor](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Ushaan-tor).

During the duel, Archer and Shran wear gauntlets on their left hand that are bound by a metal cable. Is it ever explained what that gauntlet is? Was it some sort of ice mining safety device so if one miner slipped the other could catch him?

Answer (score 4):

Just 'Plate Armor Gauntlet'.  When the actual set props were [auctioned](http://startrekpropcollector.com/trekauctions/search.pl?t=ushaan&st=1&sc=1&sp=1&sch=1&se=1&ss=1&so=1) off, it was described just as that.
[image]

None of the major knowledge-bases have any other indication.

And the [transcript](http://www.chakoteya.net/Enterprise/89.htm) for the episode refers them them as 'metal shields' (granted, no indication this was from an actual script).